# Some Changes from Mysql to Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am very new in php and sql, and I just learn it a few years ago but stop it and not update it. This is the old code I have to get the user info such as username and password.

```
 $myemail= $_POST['myemail']; 
 $mypassword= $_POST['mypassword'];

 $sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail='".$myemail."' and mypassword='".$mypassword."'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count==1)
    {
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit; 
    }
```

As how it is above, what I use is mysql. I want to learn how to change this code to mysqli. I have learned it from ws3school, and only got it like this:

```
    mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user");
```

But i get stuck for the rest code such as the `WHERE myemail='".$myemail."' and mypassword='".$mypassword."'";`

Comment: The question is: Do you want to go with prepared statements or just change this code to mysqli?

Comment: Could you please bring me to both of them? :)

Comment: go with prepared statements! Your current script is **very** vulnerable

Comment: I don't think that mysqli is good option because it is going to be depracated very soon. Use PDO for database options.

Answer (score 2):

With mysqli you have to prepare the query, this information is found in the docs.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$myemail= $_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword= $_POST['mypassword'];

$sql= "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail = ? and mypassword = ?";
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $myemail, $mypassword);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* count */
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

if($count===1){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically leave it at is is, but pull the connection in.

MySQLi (improved) still uses the same SQL statements, so you can still dynamically build them just the same. You just have to specify exactly which connection you wish to use

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail='".$myemail."' and mypassword='".$mypassword."'";
$result=mysql_query($con, $sql);
```

Note that you could also write the second line like this, which looks a little neater, especially if the rest of your code is Object Oriented.

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
```